# Python code for alternade words

Tags: python-2.7

An alternade is a word in which its letters, taken alternatively in a strict sequence, and used in the same order as the original word, make up at least two other words. All letters must be used, but the smaller words are not necessarily of the same length. For example, a word with seven letters where every second letter is used will produce a four-letter word and a three-letter word. Here are two examples:

"board": makes "bad" and "or".
  "waists": makes "wit" and "ass".
Using the word list at http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt, write a program that goes through each word in the list and tries to make two smaller words using every second letter. The smaller words must also be members of the list. Print the words to the screen in the above fashion.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

some example of what you've tried so far might help, this isn't homework exchange.

In fact you're probably gonna have this question zapped by somebody, but since its a bit of code golf here's a quick hack at it from me (untested)

```
def alternade(text, setAllWords):
    """ returns a tuple containing the two words that form the alternade
        or None if the word is not an alternade
    """
    listA = [];
    listB = [];
    textLength = len(text);
    # prevent selecting character out of range by ensuring string is even
    if textLength % 2:
        textLength += 1
        text = text + " "
    for i in range( 0, len(text), 2 ):
        listA.append(text[i])
        listB.append(text[i+1])
    strA = ''.join(listA).strip()
    strB = ''.join(listB).strip()

    if strA in setAllWords and strB in setAllWords:
        return (strA, strB)
    return None

# To do populate this set with ALL words in source word list:
setAllWords = set([ "ass", "bad", "or", "wit", "dog", "etc..." ])   

print alternade("board", setAllWords)
print alternade("waists", setAllWords)
```

of course, you'd need a set of ALL words, not just the few I've shown here, and to find working alternades you'd need to loop through the set of all words calling alternade() and ignoring those that return an empty list.

alternade(...) could also be changed to return a boolean instead of the constituent words that makeup the alternade.

(I'm sure there are Python gurus out there who can rewrite this in a more Pythonic way, but I haven't really used Python professionally for a few years now)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
f = open("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt")
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    length = len(line)
    word1 = ""
    word2 = ""
    for i in range(0, length,2):
        word1 += line[i]
        try:
            word2 += line[i+1]
        except:
            pass
        word1 = word1.strip()
        word2 = word2.strip()
        print ("==>"), word1, ("and"), word2
```